# Getting an ID from Pivot table Eloquent belongsToMany() - Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have two items. Shops & Categories. In my Shop model I have declared this relation :

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Category');
    }
```

and in my Category model I have this :

```
public function shops()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Shop');
    }
```

I am able to add Shop in to category by using attach. For example this code :

```
$shop->categories()->attach($cat_id);
```

By using the above attach method, a record is automatically created in my pivot table category_shop with category_id and shop_id.

Now, I have a shop loaded to $shop. Like below :

```
$shop           = Shop::findOrFail($id);
```

Obviously now I have my shop id in $shop->id. My question is how can I get back the category id(s) of this shop by using the above setup.? I am new to laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, shop has many categories. You will get many categories id.

```
    $shop= Shop::findOrFail($id);
    foreach($shop->categories as $category)
    {
         print_r($category->id);
    }
```